# Creating rows of data from given array in JS React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to apply TableRow of MUI. The array that I get from the database looks like below,

```
a = 
    [
      {
       id: 'aa',
       name: 'JJ',
       participants: 32
      },
      {
       id: 'aabb',
       name: 'JJbb',
       participants: 342
      },
      {
       id: 'bb',
       name: 'cc',
       participants: 332
      },
    ]

 {a[0] === undefined ? <p>No event has been found</p> : a.map((aa) => {
          <StyledTableRow key={aa.name} className={classes.tableRow}>
            <StyledTableCell component='th' scope='row'>
              {aa.id}
            </StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align='right'>{aa.id}</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align='right'>{aa.participants}</StyledTableCell>
          </StyledTableRow>
        })
        }
```

It does not show the list of the events in that table. If I try with MUI example, then it works.

```
function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
  return { name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [
  createData('Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData('Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData('Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData('Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
];

{rows.map((row) => (
            <TableRow key={row.name}>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                asdf
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
```

Even if I replace `{aa.name}, {aa.participants}, {aa.id}` to like `aaa, asdf, 234`, it does not display the table. Moreover, if I check the array `a`, it shows the correct objects inside the `.map()`. What is my mistake over here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your map function, you aren't actually returning the values. Try this:

```js
a.map((aa) => {
  return (
    <StyledTableRow key={aa.name} className={classes.tableRow}>
      <StyledTableCell component='th' scope='row'>
        {aa.id}
      </StyledTableCell>
      <StyledTableCell align='right'>{aa.id}</StyledTableCell>
      <StyledTableCell align='right'>{aa.participants}</StyledTableCell>
    </StyledTableRow>
  )
})
```

In the example from MUI, they are using implicit returns. Your example uses a code block, which requires a return statement.

You can read more about implicit returns here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body

Comment: Dang, it works. But then, how come MUI example `rows.map()` does not have return () but it still works?

Comment: Arrows functions have implicit return for one lined functions like ```x => <h2>{x}</h2>``` i means the same as ```x => { return <h2>{x}</h2> }```

Comment: @GIHYUNNAM Check my edit, I updated my answer to include a further explanation and a resource.